# Rails, entity does not updated

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activerecord, rails-activerecord

I have some entity named 'Group' and controller for some basick [CRUD](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Create,_read,_update_and_delete) actions. The problem i face is that when I'm trying to update (edit) this entity it does not get updated. I just using [update_attributes](http://apidock.com/rails/ActiveRecord/Base/update_attributes) for this:

```
def update
  group = Group.find(params[:id])
  group.update_attributes! params[:group]
  render :json => group.to_json()
end
```

And here is what i get in WEBrick console:

```
Started PUT "/groups/264.json?$$hashKey=00J&_method=PUT&group_id=null&item_sufix=null&key=null&name=ddddddddd&subgroups=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-25 00:32:03 +0200
Processing by GroupsController#update as JSON
  Parameters: {"$$hashKey"=>"00J", "group_id"=>"null", "item_sufix"=>"null", "key"=>"null", "name"=>"ddddddddd", "subgroups"=>"", "id"=>"264", "group"=>{}}
```

I suppose problem is that some why params[:group] comes empty. But why this happens as we can see that all needed fields (:name in this case) comes with request? In Group model  i do have `attr_accessible :name`

As for routes (don't actually know if they related to my problem) I have single line for this entity in my config/routes.rb:

```
resources :groups
```

and here is summary of routes for 'Group' entity:

```
          groups GET    /groups(.:format)                 groups#index
                 POST   /groups(.:format)                 groups#create
       new_group GET    /groups/new(.:format)             groups#new
      edit_group GET    /groups/:id/edit(.:format)        groups#edit
           group GET    /groups/:id(.:format)             groups#show
                 PUT    /groups/:id(.:format)             groups#update
                 DELETE /groups/:id(.:format)             groups#destroy
```

Rails version: Rails 3.2.11

Comment: To me it seems like it is the incoming request that is faulty. What is sending it and why does it look so strange?

Comment: @Jesper, I send it from AngularJS application (AJAX request), but I guess it does not matter who and how send it. What is wrong with request? As you can see i send whole object but since `name` present in request and present in attr_accessible - why it does not exists in params[:group]?

Comment: You're supposed to wrap the object data in a `"group" => {data: "goes here"}`. I see nothing of the sort in the PUT request coming in to your server. That's what's wrong.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found solution.
Output in console:

```
Parameters: {"$$hashKey"=>"00J", "group_id"=>"null", "item_sufix"=>"null", "key"=>"null", "name"=>"ddddddddd", "subgroups"=>"", "id"=>"264", "group"=>{}}
```

say that parameters are sent but it does not say nothing about how they sent. This is what knocked me up. I thought that if rails can see this parameters than they sent in proper way. When i checked - this parameters was regular POST parameters (and it can be seen from  my original post where i put request url) while rails require this parameters to be in request body (payload). This is why inner `group` remained empty.

Comment: Actually i don't know what is the best practice on SO - should i update my original post with solution or create separate answer...

Answer (score 1):

Your "group"=>{} should be wrapping your other prams such as name

"group"=>{"name"=>"ddddddddd", "subgroups"=>"", "id"=>"264"}

that tells me your submitting your arguments wrong.

Try passing your prams like group[name]=ddddddddd and group[id]=264

Comment: If i do request for entity creation I'm passing parameters as is and it work - `Parameters: {"name"=>"sssdasdasd", "group"=>{"name"=>"sssdasdasd"}}`

Comment: well I can tell you that when your update/create action passes the params[:group] its only looking in that hash so unless the attributes are in there its not using them. The top level attributes will be ignored so theres no reason to pass them like that. how would rails know that this top level name value belongs to anything?

Comment: Started PUT "/groups/264.json?$$hashKey=00J&_method=PUT&group_id=null&item_sufix=null&key=null&name=ddddddddd&subgroups=" for 127.0.0.1 at 2013-02-25 00:32:03 +0200
 is telling your what the problem is.

Comment: `how would rails know that this top level name value belongs to anything?` - I guess it can be know from values set up with attr_accessible. Isn't it?

Comment: The model only gets what your controller passes it. Right now your only passing it whats found in the groups hash. attr_accessible only says that your allowed to pass the listed arguments it does not map them.

Comment: As i found the solution it comes that my way of passing parameters is absolutely legal with only difference that they should be passed in request body. Any way, thanx for trying to help me.

Answer (score 0):

You can't use Group as a model name as it conflicts with ActiveRecord group.  Change Group to XGroup and try again.

Comment: but it work fine in `create` method of same controller: `group = Group.new params[:group]`

Comment: The ways it fails are mysterious and hard to understand, it may NOT be your problem,  but it's worth a try just to make sure.

Comment: I have another entity (model/controller) named `manufacturer` with same problem. However i checked you guess - renaming Group to Igroup does not help me a bit, except it takes 5 minutes of my life (

Comment: Sorry,  but in general you should take care when naming rails models and avoid anything that may be a rails reserved word.  A classic example is trying to add an attribute 'type' to a model.  When you do introduce a conflict,  it shows up in mysterious failures that at first are hard to figure out.  I'd still avoid Group as model name.